# Negate a line based on a string even if it contains another string which I want

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to filter out lines from server log files based on keywords like error, exception etc and color them.

```
perl -ne 'print if s/e-business|exception|environment|error/\033[1;31m$&\033[0m/gi'
```

It's been working right so far, but the issue is there is one specific error that I want to ignore. Let's say keyword `TEST`, I can negate it but this line also contains error, exception keywords. I have tried lookahead and lookbehind but the problem is error, exception, `TEST` do not come at fixed places.

So, how can I go about ignoring lines containing `TEST` (don't go on case), even if it contains other keywords that I want ?

Note: I have done it in grep already, but I am interested to accomplish it in perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a second regex

```
print if /error/i and !/test/i
```

or something similar.

Comment: ah !! it works :-) I am not sure why but I tried this earlier also, didn't work. Thanks.